# Uncaught PHP Exception SoapFault: "Not Found"

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have a problem to access to my SOAP webservice.

the senario :
i call a fonction getAccountInfos

```
private function getAccountInfos($authKey){
    $wsdlAccount = $this->container->getParameter('wsdlAccounts');
    $clientWC    = new \SoapClient($wsdlAccount, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY));

    $r = $clientWC->getAcctInformations($authKey);
    if (isset($r["data"]))
        $acctId = $r["data"]["Id"];
    else
        $acctId = "0";

    return $acctId;
}
```

when i want call getAcctInformations($authKey) i get this exception :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception SoapFault: "Not Found" at C:\wamp\www\apishop\src\Apitic\IntranetBundle\Controller\HomeController.php line 548
```

here is the var_dump :

```
var_dump($wsdlAccount) : 
  string 'http://api.web-caisse.dev/wsdl/accounts.wsdl' (length=44)
var_dump($clientWC->__getFunctions()) :
  array (size=8)
    ...
    1 => string 'UNKNOWN getAcctInformations(string $authKey)' (length=44)
    ...
```

and here my accounts.wsdl :

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?>
<definitions name='AccountsList' 
                     targetNamespace='http://api.web-caisse.dev/wsdl/accounts.wsdl' 
                     xmlns:tns='http://api.web-caisse.dev/wsdl/accounts.wsdl' 
                     xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' 
                     xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
                     xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' 
                     xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' 
                     xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

  ...

<message name='getAcctInformationsRequest'>
    <part name='authKey' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
<message name='getAcctInformationsResponse'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:array'/>
</message>

  ...

<portType name='AccountsListPortType'>
   ...
    <operation name='getAcctInformations'>
        <documentation>Returns the account information.</documentation>
        <input message='tns:getAcctInformationsRequest'/>
        <output message='tns:getAcctInformationsResponse'/>
    </operation>
  ...
</portType>

<binding name='AccountsListBinding' type='tns:AccountsListPortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>

  ...

    <!-- getAcctInformations -->
    <operation name='getAcctInformations'>
        <soap:operation soapAction='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#getAccounts'/>
        <input />
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        <output>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </output>
    </operation>

  ...
</binding>

<service name='AccountsList'>
    <port name='AccountsList' binding='tns:AccountsListBinding'>
        <soap:address location='http://api.web-caisse.dev/wsdl/accounts.wsdl'/>
    </port>
</service>
```

and my vHost :

```
# api.web-caisse.dev
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "SOAPAction, content-type"

   DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/webcaisse/apioffice
   ServerName api.web-caisse.dev
 </VirtualHost>
```

my host :

```
 127.0.0.1 api.web-caisse.dev
```

I don't understand why i have this exception because the url of my service in my wsdl is the same that my var_dump and the SOAP client know the fonction getAcctInformations($authKey)...

So thanks for the help in advance.